# $routeParams object getting empty in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngroute

Below is the code Snippet that I am trying. I am not getting values from $routeParams, even it seems  $routeProvider is not getting called. I am trying to click on the link and get values from URL parameters and change title of page when I navigate to different links by routing. Please provide your feedback if I am missing something.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html ng-app='eventApp' ng-controller='eventController' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <head>

          <title > {{title}}</title>
          <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <style>
             html, body, input, select, textarea
             {
             font-size: 1.05em !important;
             }
          </style>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">     </script>  
       </head>
       <body >
          <hr />
          Language: <a href="#/event/en" ng-class="{ 'bg-primary': language === 'en' }">en</a> | 
<a href="#/event/np" ng-class="{ 'bg-primary': language === 'np' }">np</a> | 
<a href="#/event/mt" ng-class="{ 'bg-primary': language === 'mt' }">mt</a>
          <hr />
       </body>
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
       <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
       <script>
          var cfn = angular.module('eventApp',['ngRoute']);
            cfn.config(function ($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider

           .when('/event/:language', {
               templateUrl: 'eventPage.html',
               controller: 'eventController'
           })

          });

            cfn.controller('eventController',['$scope','$routeParams', function($scope,$routeParams){
                console.log($routeParams.language);
                $scope.lang = $routeParams.language || 'en';
                if($scope.lang=='en'){
                    console.log($scope.lang);
                    $scope.title="np";
                }

                else if($scope.lang=='np'){
                    $scope.title="np";
                }

                else if($scope.lang=='mt'){
                    $scope.title="mt";
                }


          }]);


       </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: You need an ng-view for it to load your `eventPage.html` in.

Comment: @AndrewMairose this should be an answer. Also, the scripts should be inside the body, not outside.

Comment: hi I added <div ng-view></div> inside the body , but now it is running in infinite loop, the page is getting bumped with the loop of view page. Please try to run adding the ng-view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things that you are doing wrong.

1. You need to add an `ng-view` in your page for it to load your `eventPage.html`.
2. You need to remove the `ng-controller`, as you provide the controller with `ngRoute`.
3. Your `<script>` tags should be inside the `<body>` tag.
4. Instead of setting the default to `en` in your controller, you could use the `.otherwise` method of `$routeProvider` to redirect to `/event/en` whenever a language is not provided to the route.
5. You cannot access your controller's `$scope` from outside the template in your `ng-view`, so your `ng-class` directives on your anchor tags will not work, because they cannot access the `language` variable of your controller's `$scope`. There are two ways you can fix this. You can either move your language selection html into your `eventPage.html` template, or you can inject `$rootScope` into your controller, and set the language on that object.

Your HTML should look something like this:

```
<div ng-app="eventApp">
  <hr />
  Language:
  <a href="#/event/en" ng-class="{'bg-primary': language === 'en'}">en</a> | 
  <a href="#/event/np" ng-class="{'bg-primary': language === 'np'}">np</a> | 
  <a href="#/event/mt" ng-class="{'bg-primary': language === 'mt'}">mt</a> 
  <hr />
  <div ng-view=""></div>
</div>
```

And your JavaScript should look something like this (obviously with your `eventPage.html` instead of the string I used for a template):

```
var cfn = angular.module('eventApp', ['ngRoute']);

cfn.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/event/:language', {
    template: '<h1>{{title}}</h1>',
    controller: 'eventController'
  }).otherwise({redirectTo: '/event/en'});
});

cfn.controller('eventController', ['$scope', '$routeParams','$rootScope',
  function($scope, $routeParams, $rootScope) {
    $scope.title = $routeParams.language;
    $rootScope.language = $routeParams.language;
  }
]);
```

Here is a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vupuh5rq/3/).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help and guidelines.

Comment: once I put my html page in template: 'eventPage.html' I am not getting the rendered page, but string 'eventPage.html' in my page. I am also looking to load different page on template, based on $routeParams values.

Comment: I was abale to load the html page, I was missing  templateUrl:'eventPage.html', but how can I change my template based on the parameters value? Any suggestion.

Comment: You can access variables in the `$scope` object in your template. For example, if you have `$scope.title = $routeParams.language` in your controller, you can access `$scope.title` in the HTML of your template with `{{title}}`.

Comment: I wanted to rendered different  Html page in templateUrl based on $routeParams value received, Is that possible to change templateUrl.

Comment: I found the solution, rather than checking the $routeParams value, I just used different routing url,  like `when('/event/en ` `.when(/event/np` and load my template.